# Do I have to choose my character's name from the list?

Tags: dungeon-world

In Dungeon World's character creation rules, the rules for choosing a name are as follows:

> Choose your character’s name from the list.

The list of human wizard names, for example, is as follows:

> Avon, Morgan, Rath, Ysolde, Ovid, Vitus, Aldara, Xeno, Uri

Does this mean every Dungeon World human wizard player character has one of these nine names? Am I forbidden from coming up with my own name?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's PbtA tradition to just tell you to do stuff without hemming and hawing about it. It's also PbtA tradition that *the game is a conversation* and it's fine to tinker with the rules.

**Going off-list is perfectly fine as long as you take a sec to make sure the group's fine with your new choice.**

---

Here's some guidance about it from game designers.

For example, [in this thread](http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/index.php?topic=1518.0), an Apocalypse World player asks:

> Was I wrong (not wrong, but maybe not quite approaching things in the best spirit of the game) to pick my own name?
>
> If you're wondering, my character is a Maestro D' and the named I picked was Dickson.  He's the proprietor of a high class retro-Victorian brothel.

John Harper, now the designer of Blades in the Dark, replies:

> You and the GM talking about it? That's one of the reasons there are name lists.
>
> The way authority is hashed out there, between you and [the GM], and the role of the text and all: kind of like practice, in a way. Those exceptions hashed out beforehand ("Can my tank actually be a helicopter instead?") are an easy way for the group to find its feet and start the process of judgment calls and shared vision needed for play.

Vincent Baker, designer of Apocalypse World, replies:

> I think John [Harper]'s nailed it. I don't think anybody's playing this wrong, certainly not [the OP].
>
> "Can my car be a helicopter?" "Can my hardhold be a caravan of trucks, buses and vans?"  "Can my infirmary be, like, a meditative state I go into, to go with my healing touch?" "Can my name be Dickson even though it's not on the list?"
>
> The [GM] gets to say yes or no. All's well.

Comment: This is a nice piece of research.

Answer (score 16):

### Technically, Yes.

The rule in the book is pretty clear, as you quoted:

> Choose your character’s name from the list.

You find the list that matches your race and class, then pick a name.

### On the other hand

The DM's Agenda includes *portray a fantastic world*, and the Principles include *embrace the fantastic*, *name every person*, and *be a fan of the characters*. If you (or your player) wants to pick a different name, go nuts. I admit that I once let a player choose a name *from the wrong race!*

And as a side note, there are no rules about nicknames, aliases, or pseudonyms.

---

Let me expand a bit on my experience letting the thief (of course!) break this particular rule. For context, the players were all long-time RPG players and longer-time friends, with none to some experience with DW specifically. I believe the total campaign length was four sessions.

During character generation, the thief's player (full disclosure: my wife) was looking over the list of halfling rogue names and was dissatisfied. She asked if she could choose a name that wasn't on the list. At this point, I gave no real thought to the Agenda or Principles and went with the old stand by: is it fun for everyone? Sure, it probably won't hurt! Then I recalled there are rules to this game. I brought it up to the other players (*ask questions and use the answers*), and we agreed that she's stuck with picking a name from the character sheet, but that she could be flexible about which list she chose from. Thus, we ended up with a halfing thief named Sparrow.

For the other players, this had basically no effect on the game. By my estimation, there was significantly more interest when I asked the Swordmage what his sword's name was (there's no list for that). However, for my wife, she was pleased to be allowed a bit more customization to her character. By the end of character generation, she ended up playing the Paladin and the Cleric off of each other. After that, I'm not sure anyone else even remembered bending the naming rules.